# MVC SEO targeting Italy from a .uk.com domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo, multilingual

My question is quite similar, but not exactly matching what I found here: [Internationalize target country for SEO using language url path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521956/internationalize-target-country-for-seo-using-language-url-path)

The only difference is that the default (only) language (Italian) does not match the domain localisation. My business is located in UK and my MVC application is hosted on a ".uk.com" domain. The website is for a software exclusively created for Italian customers, and is intended to be targeted for Italy only.

From a SEO perspective, I have configured the routing to use sub-directories like "www.mysite.uk.com/it", but I suspect that the default URL "www.mysite.uk.com" should be localised for Italy as well.

If so, what is the best approach to achieve this in MVC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be obvious, but why not use .it domain instead of .uk.com?

Anyway, otherwise I would not duplicate content with Italian content from the root and from the /it folder. Forget the /it folder if you only have one language.

There are some SEO tips here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2

After that, just use Google Webmaster Tools:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en
Here you can configure for which country our page is intended too. Adding an Italian address into the footer cannot hurt either.

But this really is not an MVC issue at all.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I already have a .it, but I'd like to use the .uk.com for other reasons. Following your suggestion, I've removed the /it sub-folders, and I've set the target property for the domain to Italy.  Anyway, according to Google: "Country-code top-level domain names (ccTLDs) are tied to a specific country (for example .de for Germany, .cn for China), and therefore are a strong signal to both users and search engines that your site is explicitly intended for a certain country.". I'm still confused... What is going to take precedence?

Comment: There two things at work here now. You told Google that your page is for Italy. But a normal user who sees the domain would not assume this. I think technically this should work, but from a usability point of view it's confusing.

Comment: I agree. I'll see what happens in the next few months, and if things won't work as expected I'll switch to the .it. Thanks again, your suggestions have been really helpful.